# Add a list value into listbox with modal in Laravel

Tags: javascript, jquery, laravel, modal-dialog

I made below code by dynamically adding a list item to the modal box.

**index.blade.html**

```
<div class="form-group col-sm-4 col-lg-4">
   {!! Form::label('job_type', 'Type:') !!} 
   {!! Form::select('job_type', [
            '1' => '1',
            '2' => '2',
            '3' => '3',
            '4' => '4',
            '5' => '5',
            '6' => 'Add more item'            
     ], null, ['class' => 'form-control']) !!}
    </div>
```

[image]

**script.js**

```
$('#job_type').on('change', function (e) {
     if ('Add more' == this.value) {
         $("#jobListModal").modal("show");
        }
 });
$('#btnSave').click(function() {
  var newType = $('input').val();
     $('select#job_type option:last').after('<option value="'+ newType + '" selected="selected">'+ newType +'</option>');
     $('#jobListModal').modal('hide');
});
```

**modal code**

```
   <div class="modal fade" id="jobListModal">
            <div class="modal-dialog">
              <div class="modal-content">
                <div class="modal-header">
                  <button type="button" class="close" data-dismiss="modal"><span aria-hidden="true">×</span><span class="sr-only">Close</span>
                  </button>
                  <h4 class="modal-title">Insert new type</h4>
                </div>
                <div class="modal-body">
                  <p>New Job type:</p>
                  <input type="text" id="txtInput">
                </div>
                <div class="modal-footer">
                  <button type="button" class="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal">Close</button>
                  <button type="button" id="btnSave" class="btn btn-primary">Save changes</button>
                </div>
              </div>
            </div>
    </div>
```

but, I got an error when inserting a input value 'aaa', then again added a new list "KdwvCm7P5ZDUsr6Bznfm3WRNcYbaWP6jRmai12lv" not 'aaa' into list-box as new list.

So I checked data type and changed it to another, but same error occurred.
it seems like 40 random strings inserted.
How can I fix this?

This is Laravel 5.4

Comment: your line `var newType = $('input').val();` might be errorneous instead try getting specific input's value using selector, like: `var newType = $('input#txtInput').val();` and `if ('Add more' == this.value) {..` might not work as `this.value` will be `6` as per the code you posted

Comment: @SudhirBastakoti, I defined selector more finely as `$('input#txtInput').val();` So I got success, thank you :)
but I don't know why this error occurred. :(

Comment: the code `$('input').val();` will have value of first input element that exists in your page if you have more than one input element in the page, as the code does not target specific input element.